# Flex-Box Or Grid: How to align columns across multiple rows?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I created an example with react:

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-0398k)

As you can see here:

[image]

The columns are not aligned because of the dynamic width of each column. 
What do I need to do if I want all the columns to stay aligned across all rows even when they need to shrink closer together because of the window size?

**EDIT**

Same problem with css-grid:

[Code Sandbox 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-rjkq3)

Comment: Basically you can't. You need to use css-grid

Comment: @Mulgard check my ans. If it work for you. using `flex-box`.

Comment: When the window size shrinks I get the same problem with css-grid: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-0398k

Comment: remove `grid-column-gap` since `fr ` in `grid-template-columns` also takes into account the space.

Comment: Without the gap the columsn do overlap when you shrink it too much.

Answer (score 0):

I modify your `INDEX.TSX`

```
class OrderRow extends React.Component<OrderRowProps> {
    public render() {
        const { index, order } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="OrderRow">
                <div className="OrderRowIndex">{index}</div>
                <div className="columnGroup">
                    <OrderColumn values={order.number} />
                    <OrderColumn values={order.size} />
                    <OrderColumn values={order.amount} />
                    <OrderColumn values={order.price} />
                    <OrderColumn values={order.page} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also I Change many CSS.

```
*,
*:after,
*:before{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}
.Chunk {
    flex-basis: 30px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.OrderColumn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.columnGroup{
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 30px);
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.OrderColumn:first-child{
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.OrderRow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.OrderRow > div {
    /* flex: 1 1 0px; */
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.OrderRowIndex {
    flex-basis: 30px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    /* margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px; */
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.Order {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Here is your [CodeSanBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-4861q). Now it's look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the work you put in. But the overflow is no option for me.

Comment: @Mulgard Can you explain how you want exactly desktop and mobile browser? If mobile screens size `375px` how you want to place 4 `column` if one `column` items `width` more than `375px`.

Comment: I need all columns to be in one row always. so no wrapping. They should use all the space which is available and shrink the space together. they should have a minimum margin between the columns and only if there is no space left there should be horizontal overflow. The most important thing is that all columns should be aligned across all rows.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution I can live with:

[Code Pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-3o1b1)

Im using a grid with `gridTemplateColumns` being a `minmax` of minum pixel size and `fr` notation. Im still annoyed by the minimum pixel width because it is not dynamic. I would prefer if the minium width is always fitting to its content. So if there are 2 cells in a column it should be minimum of 60, if there are 3 it should be 90, and so on. So 30 px per cell.